# ros::init not working

Tags: rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am having a bit of a problem with my code. I want to write a simple node but I am getting the error "undefined reference to ros::init(....)"

My code looks somethins like this:

```
class Bridge
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "bridge");
    Bridge bridge;
};
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81081/ros::init-not-working/) by [atenea](https://answers.ros.org/users/6896/atenea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-19**:
Please update your question with more information, i.e. show the contents of your CMakeLists.txt file etc. Also what ROS version are you using?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-09-19**:
Please reply it as an answer,thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your comment Boris. I checked my CMakeLists.txt file and noticed that I didn't have rosbuild_init() in it. I added it and now it works.

---

Originally posted by [atenea](https://answers.ros.org/users/6896/atenea/) with karma: 36 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0